# Model stuck to target in StoryBoard Scene

Tags: ios, swift, module, uistoryboard

I have a could of scenes in my storyboards whose modules remain locked to a single target - if I try to delete the module and then click in some other field, a module is atomically written - with the result that, when I run a different target I have a crash while trying to open that ViewController.
I tried deleting the *customModule* field in the storyboard source but in so doing all targets start to crash.
All the other scenes normally have None instead of a specific module and thereafter work with any target.

What may be the business, and how to fix it without having the switch module each time I compile for a different target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was about adding field

```
customModuleProvider="target"
```

as in:

```
 <view contentMode="scaleToFill" restorationIdentifier="hintTable" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Lj1-Jb-0Qg" customClass="HintTable" customModule="Limo_Manager" customModuleProvider="target">
```

Apparently there is a bug in the Xcode Interface Builder skipping this field and so sticking the view to a single module. Perhaps the customModule field may be removed as it is apparently superimposed by the customModuleProvider directive, but that does not seem to harm either.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, to reference a class from a framework for example.

### Open the storyboard/xib

A) either in TextEditor:

**Objc**: delete `customModule="CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME" customModuleProvider="target"`

**Swift**: delete `customModuleProvider="target"`

---

B) or in InterfaceBuilder: untick - `Inherit Module From Target` and:

**Objc**: delete the `Module` field

**Swift**: set the `Module` field

[image]

---

In my case this works. Good luck!

`P.S running on Xcode 9`